# Inverting columns and rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, correlation

R-newbie here!
So I have data that looks like this:

rater1          1

rater1          2

rater1          3

rater2          2

rater2          3

rater2          1

I want the output to look something like this:

|rater 1 |1| 2| 3|

|rater 2 |2| 3| 1|

I had tried using the groupby() function. But it doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us an example at what your data should look like after transformation so you can do the analysis? If it is simply that your data needs transposed (rows to columns and columns to rows), the `t()` function in R does that.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for responding! And sorry about the ambiguity. I want the output to look like :  rater1  1  2 3    rater 2  1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr`solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(rater) %>%
  summarise(ratings = paste0(ratings, collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  rater  ratings
* <chr>  <chr>  
1 rater1 1,2,3  
2 rater2 1,2,3
```

If you prefer not to have a `,` between the ratings, just replace `","` by `" "` in the `collapse` argument to `paste0`.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  rater = c(rep("rater1",3), rep("rater2",3)),
  ratings = c(rep(c(1,2,3), 2))
)
```

Comment: Hello,thank you so much! But is there any way to have each rating in each cell? Eg. rater1|1|2|3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris Ruehlemanns answer. Here is a solution for your request in the comments: Using `lead` `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(rater) %>% 
  mutate(rating1 = ratings,
         rating2 = lead(ratings),
         rating3 = lead(ratings, 2)) %>% 
  slice(which(row_number() %% 3 == 1)) %>% 
  select(-ratings)
```

Output:

```
  rater  rating1 rating2 rating3
  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 rater1       1       2       3
2 rater2       1       2       3
```